# What factors decides the number of tokens to generate?

Tags: bitcoin-core, ripple, ethereum

Tron has decided to generate 100B tokens with some initial price? What parameters do these centralised crypto owners consider before deciding the number and price of tokens?

Answer (score -1):

There are no answer to that.
Depends on many things the token creators want to accomplish.